# What is RenderAtScale property of BitmapCache class for?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I see CacheMode in `Pivot` control (and other controls) like this:

```
<phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Margin="0,-5,0,0">
```

I [knew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.uielement.cachemode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) that Windows Phone just has `BitmapCache` value for it. anyway, what is [RenderAtScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.bitmapcache.renderatscale%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property of it for?

I have an app which will has lots of values in memory and I fear that a memory leak will occur. Should I use this cache? and what is the best value for `RenderAtScale` for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A question with a link to the answer in it? Sorry but have to poke fun at that. RenderAtScale would be for example if you have a `UIElement` that you're applying a `ScaleTransform` or Zooming in/out to make it larger than it is naturally, than you would also want to apply your RenderAtScale property. [See this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache.renderatscale%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

As for the best value for your scenario, well you're not messing with any Scale so I don't think you'll use it.

Careful with how you use CacheMode since it can kill performance if not used correctly. If I remember right, a lot of the WP stuff implements it automatically for elements animating things where caching helps for like Translates/Opacity/Rotates, etc etc. Also keep in mind, all the children will inherit that declaration if you set it, so you could end up with a lot of stuff cached you may not even need to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: heh, feel free.. it's easy for a `XAML` guy. but, it was the first time I see it. thanks man.

Comment: Eh, next time I'll probably be on the receiving end. We've all been there, cheers amigo